# Javascript CSS times

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to run a CSS animation with jQuery by adding a class with transition = 0s but changing the color, and instantly remove that class so (with the original transition = 2s) it goes gradually to the original color.

Below is a little example of what I'm saying, why doesn't blue1() function work? I assume that the javascript code executes so fast that the element never gets the new class added, but I'm now sure how this works behinds the scenes.
If I add the class, and then wait a time and remove the class, it works (blue2())... is there a better way to achieve this? What would be the best way to workaround this?

Thank you.

Codesnippet:

```js
function blue1(){
 $("#element").toggleClass("blue");
 $("#element").toggleClass("blue");
}

function blue2(){
 $("#element").toggleClass("blue");
 setTimeout(function(){
  $("#element").toggleClass("blue");
 }, 1000);
}
```

```css
#element{
 width:100px;
 height:100px;
 background:red;
 transition:2s;
}

#element.blue{
 background:blue;
 transition:0s;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title>Test</title>
</head>
<body>

<div id="element"></div>
<button id="button" onclick="blue1();">Run without delay</button>
<button id="button2" onclick="blue2();">Run with delay</button>
  
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You're toggling `.blue` instantly twice your transition does not have time to change your element.

Comment: I was going to create an answer but yeah @AlexG is right, you are toggling it one after another see: https://jsbin.com/nevekuhulo/edit?html,css,js,output

Comment: you can create an animation key frame for a colour transition from red to blue and then back to red, make it in css class an apply it on click, hope it helps

Comment: But if the transition time for .blue is 0s, should't the color be changed instantly, even before the class being toggled again?

Comment: @JonathanNewton the result I want is to get a fade from blue to red when the button is pressed, but the color should always be red (except during fade of course). In your example, I only change the color to blue

Comment: @BrunoGarcía "_should't the color be changed instantly_" I get what you mean, in theory you should be right, but it might be too fast for the browser to even care.

Comment: @BrunoGarcía did you see the changes?

Answer (score 2):

```js
function blue1(){
  var transition = $("#element").is(".delayRed");
  if(transition){
    $("#element").removeClass("delayRed");
  }else {
    $("#element").toggleClass("red");
  }
 
}

function blue2(){
  var alreadyRed = $("#element").is(".delayRed");
  if(!alreadyRed){
    setTimeout(function(){
  $("#element").toggleClass("delayRed");
 }, 1000);
  }
}
```

```css
#element{
 width:100px;
 height:100px;
    background:blue;
}
#element.red{
 width:100px;
 height:100px;
    background:red;
}

#element.delayRed{
 width:100px;
 height:100px;
 background:red;
    transition:2s;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.js"></script>
  
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
<div id="element"></div>
<button id="button" onclick="blue1();">Run without delay</button>
<button id="button2" onclick="blue2();">Run with delay</button>
  
</body>
</html>
```

I updated it to meet Bruno's requirements I added in an additional piece of CSS so you can toggle between the 2 colours, the caveat being you can't transition to red if the colour of the square already has the class red.

Documentation:

[`removeClass()`](https://api.jquery.com/removeclass/)

[`is()`](http://api.jquery.com/is/)

Answer (score 0):

The reason your idea is not working is because jQuery doesn't care whether you have a transition on your class for fading the blue backgorund in.

When you run `toggleClass()` it looks at the element and either adds or removes the class. On your first call it adds it, on your second call it sees the class exists, which means it immediately removes it. Removing the class also kills any transitioon you might have had running.

A better way if all you want to do is change the background colour would be using jQuery transitions and a proper selector to get your button as opposed to adding the function in the html. Like so:

```
$('#button1').onclick(function() {

  $(this).animate({
    background: 'blue'
  }, 2000, function() {

    $(this).animate({
      background: 'red'
    }, 2000);

  });

});
```

The above sets an event listener for a click on you button and then uses the `.animate()` method to animate your background property of this element to blue. We set a callback on this function to transition back to red after 2s. Change the animation numbers for other timings and I recommend you have a look at the docs for the `animate()` method below.

http://api.jquery.com/animate/